# Should JPA provider (Hibernate/Eclipselink) put unique constraint in unidirectional one to one relationship?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I started to learn about JPA 2.1 and I'm reading now aboult relationships.

There is unidirectional One-to-one relationship, defined in JSR-338 as follow (section 2.10.3.1 "Unidirectional OneToOne Relationshps"):

> The following mapping defaults apply:
>
> - Entity A is mapped to a table named A.
> - Entity B is mapped to a table named B.
>
> Table  A conttains a foreign key to table B. The foreign key column
>   name is formed as the concatenation of the following: the name of the
>   realtionship property or field of entity A; "_"' the name of the
>   primary key column in table B. **The foreign key column has the same
>   type as primary key of table B and there is a unique key constraint on
>   it.**

My problem is that unique constraint on foreign key colum does not exists, so I'm wondering if something wrong with my code.

Here is my code:

First entity

```
@Entity
public class FootballPlayer {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Ball ball;

    public FootballPlayer() {
    }

    public FootballPlayer(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setBall(Ball ball) {
        this.ball = ball;
    }

    public Ball getBall() {
        return ball;
    }
}
```

Second entity:

```
@Entity
public class Ball {

    @Id
    private long id;

    public Ball() {
    }

    public Ball(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And here is scenario that should In my opinion ends with exception:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

FootballPlayer firstPlayer = new FootballPlayer(1L);
FootballPlayer secondPlayer = new FootballPlayer(2L);
Ball ball = new Ball(10L);

firstPlayer.setBall(ball);
secondPlayer.setBall(ball);

em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(ball);
em.persist(firstPlayer);
em.persist(secondPlayer);
em.getTransaction().commit();

em.close();
emf.close();
```

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.0, defined in pom.xml as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And in-memory database Derby 10.10.1.1:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
  <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
  <version>10.10.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

persistence unit in persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="pu">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

  <class>com.mprzybylak.minefields.jpa.relationships.onetoone.uni.Ball</class>
  <class>com.mprzybylak.minefields.jpa.relationships.onetoone.uni.FootballPlayer</class>

  <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:memory:test;create=true" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="APP" />             
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
  </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

I tried to switch to eclipselink, but I still have this problem. I used eclipselink 2.5.1

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId> 
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

With following configuration of persistence unit:

```
<persistence-unit name="pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>com.mprzybylak.minefields.jpa.relationships.onetoone.uni.Ball</class>
<class>com.mprzybylak.minefields.jpa.relationships.onetoone.uni.FootballPlayer</class>

  <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"value="jdbc:derby:memory:test;create=true" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="APP" />

    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

JPA is working in way that I think it should only when I put `@JoinColumn(unique=true)` annotation on `ball` field inside `FootballPlayer` class

So, am I doing something wrong in my code? Because it is hard to belive for me, that two major JPA providers do not follow JPA specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is that you discovered a bug, it both EclipseLink and Hibernate. I think, this part of the specification was simply ignored. So you should report the bug.

PS: this is also a requirement in JPA 2.0.

Comment: I will report bug and see what hibernate/eclipselink guys think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this bug as well. I am using Derby DB with EclipseLink 2.0.0. Issue is there and I spend more than 3 hours trying to find what is wrong with my code... Obviously nothing.

Comment: Yes, I had it too some time ago when using Hibernate. Currently use DataNucleus JPA and it doesn't have the same problem FWIW

Comment: I've created issue in hibernate's jira ( https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9151 ), but it is still open. Also I tried to ask guys in eclipselink forum about it ( https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1327794/#msg_1327794) but there is no answer